# Javascript code to expand navigation bar not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, navbar

I'm working on a navigation bar for my website and I've made some Javascript to go along with the CSS. **Before you run it, make sure the result window is less than 760 pixels wide.**

```js
function compressNavbar() {
  var x = document.getElementById("navbar");
  if (x.className === "responsive-h2") {
    x.className += " responsive-h2-expand";
  } else {
    x.className = "responsive-h2";
  }
}
```

```css
ul.blue {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

ul.blue * {
  color: white;
}


/* Horizontal navbar */

ul.horizontal-navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.horizontal-navbar li {
  float: left;
}

.horizontal-navbar li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* responsive */

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  ul.responsive-h2 li {
    display: block;
  }
  ul.responsive-h2 li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    display: none;
    /* Remove all links except home and the menu button */
  }
  ul.responsive-h2-expand {
    position: relative;
  }
  .responsive-h2-expand li:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.responsive-h2-expand li {
    float: none !important;
    display: block !important;
  }
  ul.responsive-h2-expand li * {
    text-align: left !important;
  }
  ul.responsive-h2-expand li a {
    padding: 10px 14px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
  }
  ul.responsive-h2-expand li {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="responsive-h2 horizontal-navbar blue" id="navbar">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="compressNavbar()">
      Menu
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The beginning works fine - we have a nice, styled navbar with all links missing except Home and the menu button. But when I press the menu button, the expanded navbar is not styled with my `blue` class and does not feature all of my links. Additionally, when Menu is pressed again, most of my styling is missing.

What's wrong with my code that's making this happen? As I'm new to JS, I assume it's that- I think I might be doing something wrong with `className` but I don't know what or how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to use `classList.toggle`:

```
function compressNavbar() {
  var x = document.getElementById("navbar");
  x.classList.toggle("responsive-h2-expand");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not replacing `class` properly

```
function compressNavbar() {
   var x = document.getElementById("navbar");
   if (x.className === "responsive-h2") {
       x.className += " responsive-h2-expand";
       // you are not adding "blue" and "horizontal-navbar" classes back
       // ex: x.className = "responsive-h2 responsive-h2-expand horizontal-navbar blue"
   } else {
       x.className = "responsive-h2";
   }
}
```

you can use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) methods to manipulate `class` effeciently